# Multiple selection filter

Tags: filter, multi-selection

I am working on a design, however, I have hit a bit of a roadblock on a multiple selection filter. The list of filter values will not be very long.

I assume that users will not know all the available filter values, so I think search wouldn't work in this case.

I have created a basic flow - shown in the image below.
Is there a better way of doing this or does this way work?

[image: multifilter]

Comment: maybe a search would work great there!

Comment: Hi Igor, I have played with that idea but the users do not know all the available options, so I anticipate a search will not work.  What do you think?

Comment: Are you **sure** that every user will be able to map the categories to the subitems? - Is a _Periophthalmus_ a fish or an amphibian? (although it's probably not really about animals)

Comment: I mean if the user has no idea what options are available, the only way they can find it is by scrolling through the list. That's why I think that Select2 Lifecycle could work well,it gives you an option to search or scroll...

Comment: @L.Mller - I am 90% certain that the users will be able to map the categories to the subitems.  The filters will be more specific than the one shown, and its for a niche sector where the users have in depth understanding of the categories and subitems.

Comment: @Igor-G thanks for that!  I think the main defining factor is: does the user know the potential options available, if so, then search works, where as if they do not, then a list works better.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm confused why you are hiding the selections in the drop-down if you stated "the list isn't very long". Why  not expose the options and let users select/unselect as they wish?

Comment: @usingtheinternet I am hiding the selections in a drop-down as eventually there will be 6 different filters, and by 'not very long' I mean around 15 options per filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

They have great examples, I think you should use this one Select2 Lifecycle.