# How to simplify multiple filters?

Tags: usability, filter, content

There is a list of courses, which can be filtered by **Type**, **Department**, **Faculty**, **All / My**.

How the filtering part can be improved and simplified here?

[image]

Comment: Your illustration seems quite straightforward.  What don't you like about it?  You'd want to change each list on the fly to limit the remaining options based on the choices already made, but eventually you'll end up with 0, 1, or >1 courses/sections to choose from.

Comment: I agree with @MMacD. Your implementation looks clean and intuitive.

Comment: Some relevant reading material: [The Mystery of Filtering by Sorting](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/07/the-mystery-of-filtering-by-sorting.php).

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46779/multiple-selection-filter?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the possible solution I came up with

[image]

Comment: That'd work too, but you'd have to write your own widget if you want to leave the various choices visible to remind the user what search criteria yielded the result you display.  Your original sketch uses multiple dropdowns, which already exist.  Of course, if you plan to leave it open as shown, that'd consume some (perhaps a lot) of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

**Get rid of the filters. Just provide a powerful search box.**

The filters are there to help the user find the required course. It is not that the user wants to do something with the *list* of filtered courses. The box will search each of the fields, Faculty, Department, etc. You can empower it with auto-completion and textual filters. See, for example, the way Gmail search bar is working.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUzccP.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>